GitHub Workflow setup-ruby action. How to do custom gem install in the middle
I have a GitHub Workflow file that looks like this:
name: "Ruby on Rails CI"
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:11-alpine
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: rails_test
          POSTGRES_USER: rails
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    env:
      RAILS_ENV: test
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://rails:password@localhost:5432/rails_test"
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: install Nokogiri alone
        run: sudo gem install nokogiri -v 1.16.4
      # Add or replace dependency steps here
      - name: Install Ruby and gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true
      # Add or replace database setup steps here
      - name: Set up database schema
        run: bin/rails db:schema:load
      # Add or replace test runners here
      - name: Run tests
        run: bin/rake

  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install Ruby and gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@55283cc23133118229fd3f97f9336ee23a179fcf # v1.146.0
        with:
          bundler-cache: true
      # Add or replace any other lints here
      - name: Security audit dependencies
        run: bin/bundler-audit --update
      - name: Security audit application code
        run: bin/brakeman -q -w2
      - name: Lint Ruby files
        run: bin/rubocop --parallel

When I run it, I get this error during the "Install Ruby and Gems" section. It's extremely long, confusing, and full of stuff I don't think is relevant. It seems to have to do with nokogiri (I've never had nokogiri work without some intense messing about):
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/runner/work/admin-tool/admin-tool/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.16.4/ext/nokogiri
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.5/x64/bin/ruby -I
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.5/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r
./siteconf20240508-1911-jrafce.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
...
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... no
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -llibxslt... no
checking for libxslt using `pkg_config`... no
Please install either the `pkg-config` utility or the `pkg-config` rubygem.
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... no
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -llibxslt... no
-----
extconf.rb:295:in `ensure_package_configuration'
extconf.rb:711:in `<main>'
xslt is missing. Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
...
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/home/runner/work/admin-tool/admin-tool/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/nokogiri-1.16.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
...
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.16.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.

This is extremely confusing, because earlier in the workflow, I specifically put sudo gem install nokogiri -v 1.16.4 and that worked, saying the gem had been installed:
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.16.4-x86_64-linux
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.16.4-x86_64-linux
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.16.4-x86_64-linux
Done installing documentation for nokogiri after 2 seconds
1 gem installed

I cannot look at the files it tells me to (because it's all wrapped up in this workflow), so I'm not really sure where to start with a solution.
However, even if I did know what options were needed to use to get nokogiri going, I cannot seem to put them in the workflow file in a way that will be recognized. The Ruby setup section is a monolith; I don't know how to run custom stuff inside of it.

Have you tried adding the pkg-config gem to your gem file?

you got 2 install ruby section with different action, one is with ruby/setup-ruby@v1
which one is failing and have you tried to use the other action to see whether it still fail?

Don't you have nokogiri specified in your gemspec file? With your current workflow, move its installation step after setup-ruby and try again.

@dbugger : I have not as yet. I'm trying not to change the gemfile because it all works in local and production environments, and I don't want to risk messing up those environments just to get automated testing working. Thank you for the suggestion, though!

@Justin : Good point out. I copied this workflow from one of the Github examples. The second section is just for linting, and it's failing with the same error. I just didn't mention it because I don't really care about the linting section; just testing. I should have removed it from the question. Apologies about that.

@Azeem : Our project doesn't have a gemspec file. It's not a gem itself, but a monolithic Ruby on Rails application. If I move the installation of nokogiri to after the setup-ruby step, it fails with the given error because it's the setup-ruby step that is failing. Thank you for the suggestion!
